# Insert into database with ajax from a joomla 3 module

Tags: module, security, database, ajax

I have seen a lot of inquiries about ajax, but normally there are about retrieving data from database. I was wondering about how to insert data directly interacting inside a module.

I have a module with listings retrieved from database and I would like that registered users can keep certain information from the module to be accessed later. It would be fine just to have a button near each element from the list to save it to a table maybe with two columns: User and Element ID.

I have researched and it seems that is easy using a wrapper calling a php script that inserts the records, but I am sure that this is a problem for security.
Any ideas, please?

Comment: I'd recommend including some of the code that you're seen that is close.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible. Check this com_ajax example, saving information in the user session:

**Using Joomla Ajax Interface**
https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface

**Ajax-Session-Module**
https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface

**Ajax-Session-Plugin**
https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/Ajax-Session-Plugin

If you are going to implement your own tables, all requests must be associated with the current userid in module for "registered" users only.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar recently except i'm deleting from the database. I'm guessing you can modify the code to update instead.

This is the ajax call in default.php

```
<script>
function ajaxDeleteEvent(finput)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"index.php?   option=com_jobApplications&task=deleteApplication&id", 
        method:'POST',
        data: "id="+finput,
        success:
            function(data)
            {
                $("#container-"+finput).remove();
                console.log(data); 
            },
        error:
            function(e)
            {   
                console.log("u done goofed");
                console.log(e.message);
            }
    });
}
</script>
```

And in controller.php i have

```
public function deleteApplication()
{
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication(); 
    $id = JRequest::getVar("id",null,"post","int");
    // Check if id is set
    if ( isset( $id ) )
    {
        // remove that application from database
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        ...

    }   
    $mainframe->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Controller method that can be called by ajax request ([may this help](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10814/call-controllers-publish-function-from-outside/12106#12106)).

This method will insert in the database using the db instance of joomla.

Then, all you need is is call the ajax by a onClick event in your module.