# Call controller's publish-function from "outside"

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, controller

I modified the publish-function of my sub-controller as follows

```
    /**
     * publish function.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function publish()
    {
        $app                                    =   JFactory::getApplication();
        $jinput                                 =   JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $ids                                    =   $jinput->get('cid', '', 'array');
        $task                                   =   $this->getTask();

        foreach($ids as $id)
        {
            // do fancy stuff
        }

    }
```

Now I really would like to change the status of some items (-> $ids) via an CLI-script.

Is it possible to call this controller, get the method "publish" and submit a set of ids and, assigned to this, a task (publish, unpublish, trash, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but your have to create your own CLI script to translate the command line to the Joomla API command. For example:

- To receive a list of IDs (comma separated) from an argument
- Initialize JInput,
- and send it to your controller.

You can check any of the cli/ script to create your own script.

Answer (score 1):

Recently i made a component when i change the o publish status via Ajax request.

I made a method `setPublish($id, $status)` on model, and two methods on my  controller:

```
public function setPublishTrue(){
   $data = JRequest::get('post'); //get the item id via post
   $model = $this->getModel('Promocaos');
   $model->setPublish($data['id'], 1);

}
```

The ajax request:

```
        var formdata = $("#form-" + this.id).serialize();

        if(state){
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 6000,
            url: "index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=setPublishTrue&controller=mycontroller",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false
        });
```

Then, i can change the status via Ajax requests